# StringIO() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given) Python, а нужно указать 3 параметра

Tags: python, веб-программирование, flask, csv, plotly

У меня закачивается csv файл через кнопку в приложении plotly dash.
строка чтения файла у меня:

```
csv_file = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(decoded.decode('utf-8'), sep = ';',parse_dates=["колонка_с_датой_в_csv"]))
```

Но при запуске кода у меня выходит данная ошибка в cmd:

```
StringIO() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
```

Подскажите, как решить проблему, так как 3 аргумента мне нужны для чтения файла.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам, может, и нужны три аргумента, а StringIO нужны максимум два. Нужно быть внимательнее в расстановке скобок и в том, какие аргументы в какую функцию передаются

```
csv_file = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(decoded.decode('utf-8'), sep = ';'), parse_dates=["колонка_с_датой_в_csv"])
# ...................................................................^
```

*PS. Лично я разделил бы на две строчки, чтобы было легче читать и понимать. Да и со скобками тогда сложнее запутаться.*

```
data = io.StringIO(decoded.decode('utf-8'), sep = ';')
csv_file = pd.read_csv(data, parse_dates=["колонка_с_датой_в_csv"])
```